# Rapid VLAN assigment on huawei quidway s2300 switches

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I'm newbie network enginner wondering is there a way to assign same vlan to multiple ports rapidly (not separately)?
Somehow like this: "int eth 0/0/1 0/0/9 0/0/15 default vlan 101"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used that particular brand of switch before but practically every other vendor has an interface *range* command. For instance on Cisco I can do `int range Gi0/1-5` and will then be in interface configuration mode for all those ports simultaneously where I could then do `switchport access vlan xxx`.

If you search any manual you might have for that switch for "range" you should hit on it - if supported.